# When to use ContextAPI In React , avoiding prop drilling

Tags: reactjs

I have an application in which im having to pass props atleast 3 levels down, I'm trying to keep it as clean as possible with other resources like render props or render functions, but im considering using a ContextAPI for that, to avoid prop drilling, is it a good case, or 3 levels isn't that bad?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's going to be a judgment call. There is no clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing bad in having a small context if you see that the pattern fits cleanly in your scenario. And also it is recommended to use multiple small contexts to not have unnecessary or unwanted rerenders. But on the other hand, you shouldn't make an abuse of the context as well. At first, sight seems that the context might help you. If you provide more details would be better.